# How to record the data (like the number of queue) each day in Anylogic?

Tags: java, model, simulation, anylogic

I want to record the number of people leaving from the timeout every day and make a chart to show the daily condition. However I only know how to record the accumulated quantity, but I don't know how to re-record the data every day. Hope to get help from you, thank you very much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJDW7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvZ8h.png)

Comment: Define a variable and an event happening at the end of each day that assigns the daily number to that variable. You can also set the variable value to zero after recording the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an event that runs once per day, and a collection or dataset called dailyValues that collects the daily data.

Then you can just do

```
dailyValues.add(Can_Not_Wait_entrance);

Can_Not_Wait_entrance=0; //reset if needed`
```

And that's it